Analyticity of an "Integral" type function.
I found the following exercise in Conway's complex analysis.
Determine the region in which
$
f(z) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{{t - z}} \, dt
$  is analytic.

Welcome to MathSE! Please see how to ask a good question. It’s better to show your attempt in the post. What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?

Hint: Morera's theorem

You should first determine a reasonable Domain for $f$

@Lorago can you please elaborate a bit more?

I claim that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$. Let $\Delta$ be a triangular contour in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$ not containing $[0,1]$ containing $[0,1]$ in its interior region. Then
$$\int_\Delta f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_\Delta\int_0^1\frac{1}{t-z}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_0^1\int_\Delta\frac{1}{t-z}\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}t=0$$
as
$$\int_\Delta\frac{1}{t-z}\,\mathrm{d}z=0$$
by Cauchy's integral theorem (the integrand is analytic on $\Delta$ and its interior region) and where the interchange of integrals is a simple consequence of Fubini's theorem as
$$\int_\Delta\int_0^1\left\lvert\frac{1}{t-z}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\lvert z\rvert\leq\max_{(t,z)\in[0,1]\times\Delta}\left\lvert\frac{1}{t-z}\right\rvert\operatorname{Length}(\Delta)<\infty$$
by simple esimation. The claim now follows by Morera's theorem. If $z\in[0,1]$, then the integral does not even converge (check this for yourself).
